# development.log is not affected by ignore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

Part of my .gitignore looks like below:

```
## Ignore logs
/log/
/log/development.log
```

Yet `development.log` is always in modified files when commiting.

I tried to remove `--cached` and remove file altogether. No luck.
Also I have recently pushed it to remote (by mistake).

Any idea how to solve that bugger once and for all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
log/*
```

(without leading slash)

And probably

```
git rm --cached log/development.log
```

to remove the file from index.
You may also check this question [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore) to remove accidentally commited log file.

Comment: I have used `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>` mentioned in the thread that you have linked. For now looks like the problem is gone. Thanks.